# Bowling score calculator PHP form submit via AJAX

Tags: php, ajaxform

I have been building a bowling score calculator.

The calculator itself works but you must enter all scores in the form at once and then it will calculate the total score.

I wanted it to loop form the form to enter your score for each frame, submit the form show the current score and reload the form again for the next frame.

This is the first time I have used ajax and followed a tutorial on how to submit a form via ajax but it does not seem to be working.

The two scripts are below.

PHP Script:

```
    <?php
session_start();    
    //start a new game
    if (isset($_GET["endGame"]) && $_GET["endGame"] == 'yes') {
        session_destroy();
        //redirect to homepage and remove any get parameters
        $location="http://localhost/bbc/v8.php";
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL='.$location.'">';
    }

    //Check if the number of players has been set
    if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
        //Determine thye number players
        foreach ($_POST['numberOfPlayers'] as $player) {
            $_SESSION['numberOfPlayers'] = $player;
            $location="http://localhost/bbc/v8.php";
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL='.$location.'">';
        }
    //check number of players has been set before enter player names
    } elseif (isset($_SESSION['numberOfPlayers'])) {
        $numberOfPlayers = $_SESSION['numberOfPlayers'];

        if (!isset($_POST['playerSubmit']) || (isset($_POST['scores']))) {
?>
            <!-- Form to enter the playes names -->
            <form method="post" action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <?php 
                         $x = 1;
                         echo '<div class="custTitle"><h3>Enter player names below</h3></div>';
                         while ($x <= $numberOfPlayers) {
                            echo '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="players[]" placeholder="Player ' . $x . '">';
                            $x++;
                         }

                     ?>
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" name="playerSubmit" value="Start Game">
            </form>

<?php
        }// close if
    }

        if (isset($_POST['playerSubmit'])) {

            $players = array();
            foreach ($_POST['players'] as $player) {
                $players[] =  $player;
            }

            // save player names array to session for reuse
            $_SESSION['players'] = $players;
        }

        //Check player name have been submitted
        if(isset($_POST['playerSubmit']) || isset($_SESSION['players'])) {

            //create global variable of players array
            $players = $_SESSION['players'];

            $_SESSION['frameScore'] = array(0);
            $frameCount = 1;
            while ($frameCount <=9 ) {

?>
                <!-- Form to enter players score-->
                <form method="post" action="" class="ajax">
<?php
                $i = 0;
                while($i < $_SESSION['numberOfPlayers']){

                    echo '<fieldset>';
                    echo '<h3>' . $players[$i] . '</h3>';

                    $x=1;
                    // loop the form 21 times for  maximum of 21 throws
                    while($x <= 3){
    ?>
                        <label>Throw, <?php  echo $x; ?></label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="score[<?php  echo $i; ?>][<?php  echo $x; ?>]">
                                <option value="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">X</option>
                            </select>
    <?php
                        $x++;
                    }// close 21 throws while
    ?>
                            <input type="hidden" name="player[<?php  echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php  echo $players[$i]  ?>">
                        </fieldset>

    <?php
                    $i++;
                }// close while for looping throuhg players
    ?>
                        <input type="submit" value="Finish Game" name="scores"/>
                    </form>
    <?php 
            // close player submit if

            // check if any scores have been submitted
            if(isset($_POST['score'])) {
                $i = 0;
                $result = [];
                foreach($_SESSION['players'] as $name) {
                    $result[$name] = $_POST['score'][$i];
                    $pins = $_POST['score'][$i];
                    $game = calculateScore($i, $pins);
                    $i++;
                }

            }

            $frameCount++;
        }// close do while

    // if number of players is not yet set the show the form to select number of players
    } else {

?>
        <!-- Form to select the number players -->
        <h2>How many players will be bowling?</h2>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <select class="form-control" name="numberOfPlayers[]">
                <option name="numberOfPlayers[]" value="1">1</option>
                <option name="numberOfPlayers[]" value="2">2</option>
                <option name="numberOfPlayers[]" value="3">3</option>
                <option name="numberOfPlayers[]" value="4">4</option>
                <option name="numberOfPlayers[]" value="5">5</option>
                <option name="numberOfPlayers[]" value="6">6</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next">
        </form>
<?php

    }// close else

    // if the number of players has been set show a 'New Game' button
    if (isset($_SESSION['numberOfPlayers'])) {
        echo '<button class="btn_lrg"><span><a href="http://localhost/bbc/v8.php?endGame=yes">New Game</a></span></button>';
    }

    // function to calculate the players scores
    function calculateScore($player, $pins) {
        global $players;
        $frame = 0;
        // create an array for the frame score
        //$frameScore = $_SESSION['frameScore'];
        //$frameScore = array(0);
        //loop for 10 frames of a game
        while ($frame <=9) {

            $_SESSION['frameScore'][$frame] = array_shift($pins);

            //Check for a strike
            if($_SESSION['frameScore'][$frame] == 10) {

                $_SESSION['frameScore'][$frame] = (10 + $pins[0] + $pins[1]);
                // No strike, so take in two throws   

            } else {

                $_SESSION['frameScore'][$frame] = $_SESSION['frameScore'][$frame] + array_shift($pins);

                //Check for a spare
                if($_SESSION['frameScore'][$frame] == 10) {
                    $_SESSION['frameScore'][$frame] = (10 + $pins[0]);
                }

            }// close if

            //Move to the next frame and loop again  
            $frame++;
        }// close while

        //echo out player scoreborad
        echo '<h3>' .$_SESSION["players"][$player]. '</h3>' . '<h4>' . array_sum($_SESSION['frameScore']) . '</h4>';
    }// end calculateScore function

?>



<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<!-- End Bowling Calculator Script -->
```

Javascript/Ajax:

```
    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {

    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {

            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

            data[name] = value;

        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
        });

        return false;

});
```